# How does AWS Connector for GitHub use the write permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codestar

I'm trying to find an explanation why the AWS CodeStar connector for GitHub needs write permission to administration, code and pull requests.
There is no mentions about it in the [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/connections-create-github.html#connections-create-github-cli)

I feel uncomfortable that I can't opt out it.

[image]